# Unknown attribute :attribute name active resource rails

Tags: ruby, activeresource

I have a rails application that interacts with third party application and this third party application saves and to their database. Hence I am using Activeresource module.

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
self.site = "API URL"
end
```

In my view page, which is filling the information of a person, I have `:contact_address attribute` for address field.

But my third party application expects to send the params of a form in certain format like for an address it is **secondary_address** column that is there in their db.

So In my rails application I am mapping my rails params to their db schema columns.
like **secondary_address = params[:user][:address]**

While submitting the form, it does make an api call to the third party application along with these params and saves it successfully.

**But When I try to fetch a record from my rails application as 
`User.first`, I am getting the error as
"Unknown attribute: secondary_address"**

Any ideas/suggestions will be highly appreciated.!!

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON that the find would receive?